# Stored procedures and unit testing

Tags: mysql, regex, unit-testing, stored-procedures, database-testing

Does anybody know of a framework (or methodology) to unit test stored procedures just using SQL and be able to produce a reasonable report as to what has passed and what has failed (something similar to CPPUnit)?

Comment: One would have to assume some sort of data state or precondition, right?  Good question.  Hopefully, no one answers: do not use SPs.

Comment: I guess any existing xUnit testing framework would work - you would just have a major setup dependency - the actual test database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MyTAP will probably be what you are looking for, you can find it in Github

it describes itself as: '*a unit testing framework for MySQL 5.x written using fuctions and procedures. It includes a collection of TAP-emitting assertion functions, as well as the ability to integrate with other TAP-emitting test frameworks.*'

MyTAP is now hosted at `[https://github.com/hepabolu/mytap][1]`

Comment: Two comments really. 1) the question you refer to is now closed marked off topic, 2) the link you provide to github is broken, returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try STK/Unit, which is written in pure SQL and supports the ideas of Test Case and Test Suite. Also, supports expectations.
http://stk.wikidot.com/stk-unit